# Java - error definicion vector multidimensional

Tags: java, array

Estoy tratando de corregir el error que tengo sobre el siguiente método:

```
public static void sortAverageGradesAndShowIndices(double[] averageNotes) {
        double OrderedNotes[][] = new double[][];
        
        for (int i=0; i<OrderedNotes.length; i++){      // guardar array en nuevo array con 
                                                         //posicion
            OrderedNotes[i][0] = averageNotes[i];
            OrderedNotes[i][1] =i;
            
        }
        
        // ordenar en funcion de la nota
        for (int i=0; i<OrderedNotes.length; i++){              //bucle para comparar
            for (int j=i+1; j<OrderedNotes.length; j++) {
                if (OrderedNotes[i][0]> OrderedNotes[j][0]) {
                        int temp_1 = OrderedNotes[i][0];        // guardar nota en variable 
                                                                 //auxiliar
                        int temp_2 = OrderedNotes [i][1];       // guardar posicion nota en var. 
                                                                 //auxiliar
                        OrderedNotes[i][0]= OrderedNotes[j][0]; //intercambiar posicion nota
                        OrderedNotes[i][1]= OrderedNotes[j][1]; //intercambiar posicion de 
                                                                 //posicion original
                        OrderedNotes[j][0]=temp_1;              // guardar nota mayor detras
                        OrderedNotes[j][1]=temp_2;              // guardar posicion de nota mayor 
                                                                //atras
                }
            }
        }
        return OrderedNotes;

    }
```

Estoy casi seguro que mi error está aquí: `double OrderedNotes[][] = new double[][];`
Está bien definido? Debo indicar el tamaño del vector? Y si no conozco el tamaño?

Este vector contiene vectores con las variables nota y posición.

El input es un vector con notas.
Los pasos que doy son:

1. crear un vector multidimensional para almacenar la nota y posición original
2. guardar en dicho nuevo vector, la información del vector del input
3. ordenar de mayor a menor las tuplas nota-posición del input en el nuevo vector

IntelliJ me muestra 13 errores marcándome `OrderedNotes` y en `for (int i=0; i<OrderedNotes.length; i++)` me muestra como solución "Buscar dependencia", pero no sé por qué ocurre esto.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Te falta especificar la cantidad de filas y columnas de tu matriz.

Ejemplo:

```
final int FILAS = 5, COLUMNAS = 4;

double OrderedNotes[][] = new double[FILAS][COLUMNAS]; 
//Se crea una matriz de 5 filas y 4 columnas
```

Comment: he visto los errores ya. He definido mal 'OrderedNotes' pero no como indicas porque no sé cuántas filas o columnas tendrá. Debo hacerlo con la longitud del vector del input. Además, me sobra una llave (he editado para quitarla)

Comment: Utiliza `averageNotes.length` en su lugar